# Missing mfc140u.dll error when trying to run GOG Galaxy using PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

> err:module:import_dll Library mfc140u.dll (which is needed by L"C:\Program Files (x86)\GOG Galaxy\GalaxyClient.exe") not found
>
> err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\Program Files (x86)\GOG Galaxy\GalaxyClient.exe" failed, status c0000135

I have ran vcrun2015 using winetricks and I still get that error, and that seems to be the only fix I could find online. Any help would be very very appreciated, I've been trying to solve this for 12 hours :'(. Please keep it noob friendly as I have just started using Ubuntu.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't have the time to read, but you might be interested [in this](https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/5p62v0/gog_galaxy_gwent_is_any_way_to_install_it_via/). On aside note, I have never worked with playonlinux myself, but from my experience of getting asked about it by buddies it only complicates the matter, try using wine directly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding it to your [lutris](http://lutris.net/) cloud library and then running it.